# How does 'alpha' in matplotlib work with respect to zorder, and how can one blend colors symmetrically?

Tags: python, matplotlib, alpha

So, I've been messing around with `matplotlib` and found out this. If I plot different symbols atop each other *with `alpha` less than 1*:

```py
kwdict_plot={
    'marker':'o', 
    'markersize':70,
    'alpha':0.6,
    'markeredgewidth':0,
}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(6,3))
ax[0].plot([ sqrt(3/4)],[-0.5], color='r', **kwdict_plot)
ax[0].plot([         0],[ 1  ], color='g', **kwdict_plot)
ax[0].plot([-sqrt(3/4)],[-0.5], color='b', **kwdict_plot)
ax[0].set_xlim([-3,3])
ax[0].set_ylim([-3,3])
ax[0].set_aspect('equal')
ax[0].set_title('r->g->b')
ax[1].plot([-sqrt(3/4)],[-0.5], color='b', **kwdict_plot)
ax[1].plot([         0],[ 1  ], color='g', **kwdict_plot)
ax[1].plot([ sqrt(3/4)],[-0.5], color='r', **kwdict_plot)
ax[1].set_xlim([-3,3])
ax[1].set_ylim([-3,3])
ax[1].set_aspect('equal')
ax[1].set_title('b->g->r')
fig.tight_layout()
```

Then the final color seems to be affected by the order with which symbols are drawn.

[image: See the code above]

I always believed that alpha channel represents the transparency that it would act as an multiplicative operation on the spectrum it transmits. Just like simulating the cellophane papers or colored filters with different colors. Apparently this seems not the case in `matplotlib`.

So, how does it work actually? And how can I get the colors mixed symmetrically?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702176/is-it-possible-to-do-additive-blending-with-matplotlib)?

Comment: @ParthShah Not exactly what I've been looking for, but I'll try to look into it. But what I wanted to know is if there are solutions native to `matplotlib`, since I thought there should be.

Comment: To clarify, the exact behaviour I want is that, for `alpha<1`, it makes the White `(1,1,1)` background to become the color of the choice (with `alpha` applied with whatever the function appropriate) `(r,g,b)`, and if I draw it in front of some other color, `(A,B,C)` then the color would look like `(rA, gB, bC)`. There could be other options for mixing colors with alpha channel, so I'd like to know how many options do I have.

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colors.html), when zorder is used with alpha, the colors are updated as follows:

```
RGB = RGBold * (1 - alpha) + RGBnew * alpha
```

where RGBnew is whichever color has higher zorder, and RGBold is the one with lower zorder, and alpha belongs to RGBnew.  I believe the white background counts as the lowest layer, so where two circles overlap, there are three colors being mixed.  On the left, for example, we have a region with green over red over white, which becomes

```
RGB1 = white * 0.4 + red * 0.6
RGB2 = (RGB1) * (0.4) + (green) * 0.6 = red * 0.24 + green * 0.6
```

On the right, the same region instead is red over green over white, producing

```
RGB2 = green * 0.24 + red * 0.6
```

If you want the two regions where green overlaps with red to be the same, then you won't be able to choose the same alpha for both colors in both cases -- the green will have to be weaker than red in the first case, and v.v. for the second, to offset the imbalance created by compounding the alphas.  You could choose 0.6 for red (left) and green (right), and then 0.375 for green (left) and red (right).